# Are there any high level explanations of how Zend Framework 2 all fits together?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am currently playing around with Zend Framework 2.

Do any of you know of any high level explanations of how Zend Framework 2 all fits together?

I am not talking about a tutorial which shows you how to quickly get a website up and running using ZF2; I mean an easy to read "behind the scenes" guide which explains which code does what. This could be a simple explanation step by step of how ZF2 starts a project, loads each module, does the correct routing and then sends the correct output to the user.

I know it is possible to step through all the code using the debugger, but for beginners this is very painful without first understanding ZF2's architecture.

Does this exist?

Possibly even some sort of architecture diagram or UML?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I watched this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsOrT1R6IQ0

It basically goes over the DI, ServiceManager and EventManager and explains the theory behind the use of modules. It is quite long (45 mins or so) but it did give me a good general overview.

Hope that helps a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you are looking for (not all by any means) can be found in the [Zend/MVC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.intro.html) component reference.

However it is not very concise and user friendly.